# Associative binary operation with an identity, and all elements have finite order. Show this is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $S,\star$ be an associative binary structure with identity $e$. Assume that for every $s\in S$ there is an integer $n_s>0$ such that $s^{n_s}=e$. Show that $S,\star$ is a group.

I am not sure what to do for this problem. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $s\star s^{n_s-1}$?

Comment: I changed the title to something useful. Regards

Answer (score 10):

Most properties of groups are presupposed in the problem statement.  The important thing we need to establish is the existence of inverses.

We know that, for every $s$ in the structure, there exists an $N$ with the property that $s^N = e$.  So, with a little rearranging, we have $s⋆(s^{N-1}) = e$.  Given this, what is the inverse of our element $s$?